# Push notifications for PWA

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Hello to the entire community!

Can you tell me, if I implement PWA for my site and customize push notifications, do I understand correctly that if a client will not sign up for push notifications in the system permission, PWA will not be able to do anything and in order to re-enable them, the client needs to unblock them manually in the phone settings?

I would like to understand the following point, I am also implementing notification settings so that the client can subscribe/unsubscribe from fluffs from my server. What would happen if the client unsubscribed from the push notifications beforehand in the phone settings when starting the app, but then later went to the notification settings and selected the "subscribe" slider. I understand correctly that PWA will not be able to do this and all I can do is display a UI mockup to the client with instructions on how to turn off the lock from the PWA site in the phone settings

I'd really like to see a detailed and accessible answer for someone new to this